# Setting voxel color and transparency in Mayavi Mlab

Tags: mayavi, mayavi.mlab

How can I set the color and transparency of a specific voxel in Mayavi Mlab?

Answer (score 0):

What is a "specific voxel?"  Does that refer to a point on a surface?  A point on a 2D picture?  A cell?  The ease of doing this differs considerably depending on the source type and on what you are doing.

See [How to directly set RGB/RGBA colors in mayavi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431099/how-to-directly-set-rgb-rgba-colors-in-mayavi/19431100#19431100) and https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/92#issuecomment-29133606